# What is the equivalent of Ubuntu file command in Debian?

Tags: debian

To get metadata for a file in Ubuntu, I can use `file` command:

For example for `file ~/Downloads/animation.gif` it prints:

> /home/username/Downloads/animation.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 572 x 834

I wanted to do the same thing on Debian, but the `file` command is not there. Without installing new stuff, is there an equivalent available on Debian?

Answer (score 6):

> Without installing new stuff, is there an equivalent available on Debian?

The equivalent in Debian is `file`, in fact the Ubuntu package is [imported as-is from Debian in most releases](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file). `file` is part of the standard installation of Debian, but a minimal installation might not have it (*e.g.* the base Debian container images don’t ship it by default); in such scenarios, you won’t get very far without installing anything.

To install `file`, run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install file
```